# TFS/VS Workspace mapping issues

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We migrated to VSTS in the cloud and now one of the machines is having an issue with a workspace mapping and I feel I've tried everything I can Google and can not seem to figure it out.  The old TFS server was local and is no longer online.

When I try to set up a workspace I get the following error:

"The working folder C:\Users\adcbuild\Documents\ADC\TFS is already in use by the workspace ADCBUILD;Build User on computer ADCBuild"

When I run "tf vc workspaces" it returns that there are none and when I include the collection it also says there are none.

"tf vc workspaces /remove:*" says there are no cache matches

So how do I delete this "ADCBUILD;Build User" workspace.

Comment: found that using "tf workspaces /computer:* /owner:*" lists A LOT of workspaces that should be deleted but when I try to delete them it says they are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to delete this rogue workspace with the Sidekick program not sure what it does that I wasn't doing from the command line.

Comment: You could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: @Andy Li-MSFT sorry about that thought I had done that.